# Routing not working in production

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I was developing a web application in Angular 2, its working fine in my localhost, but when i hosted in production environment its not working
my sub-domain is replacing with empty string

My production server is 
**http://foobar:8888/Hrms**

where "Hrms" is sub-domain that is where i hosted my "publish files"

when i run in local the url was : **http://localhost:50739/#/access/login**
and in server the sub-domain missing automatically : **http://foobar:8888/#/**

i tried **http://foobar:8888/hrms/#/access/login** but it still going to **http://foobar:8888/#/** automatically

**Code**

```
var domainName = "";
if (location.hostname !== "localhost")
    domainName = "HRMS/";

const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: "access", component: AccessComponent,
    children: [
        { path: "", redirectTo: "login", pathMatch: "full" },
        { path: domainName + "login", component: LoginComponent, data: { title: "Login" }, canActivate: [UserGuard] },
        { path: domainName + "forgot-password", component: ForgotPasswordComponent, data: { title: "Forgot Password" }, canActivate: [UserGuard] },
        { path: domainName + "not-found", component: PageNotFoundComponent, data: { title: "Page Not Found" } },
        { path: domainName + "lock-me/:path", component: LockComponent, data: { title: "Locked" }, canActivate: [LockGuard] }
    ]
},
{
    path: "app", component: LayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
        { path: "", redirectTo: "getting-started", pathMatch: "full" },
        { path: domainName + "dashboard", component: DashboardComponent, data: { title: "Dashboard" } },
        { path: domainName + "getting-started", component: GettingStartedComponent, data: { title: "Getting Started" } },
        { path: domainName + "accounts", component: AccountsComponent, data: { title: "Accounts" } },
        { path: domainName + "organization", component: OrganizationComponent, data: { title: "Organization" } },
        { path: domainName + "interviews", component: InterviewsComponent, data: { title: "Interviews" } }
    ]
},
    { path: "", redirectTo: domainName + "access/login", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "**", redirectTo: domainName + "access/not-found", pathMatch: "full" }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true })
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRouting { }
```

Please let me know, when did i do wrong
Thanks.

Comment: try <base href="./Hrms/">

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change your base `tag` in your `index.html` file:

`<base href="/">` to `<base href="/hrms">`

This tag is used by angular router to know where is the base of every route, that's why it's not working in production while it works in dev.

Comment: Thanks this working but, when i go to "http://foobar:8888/hrms" its redirecting to "http://foobar:8888/hrms/#/access/login" here its fine but  when i refresh the browser manually or Ctrl+f5 base href, prefixing to the url like this "http://foobar:8888/hrms/hrms/#/access/login" any idea why ?

Comment: yeah, this is an apache configuration.

Comment: @Arjun See: https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/

Comment: This may be helpful if the above does not work for you.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5113#issuecomment-335308252

Answer (score 4):

When building use the --base-href property as follows:

`ng build --prod --base-href /hrms`

Answer (score 1):

As  @supamiu said, most likely the problem is in base href. But instead of hard coding  a path in index.html, when gerating your production artifacts, use flag --base-href your_app_prefix. That way final index file will contain correct base href and app should work as expected.

Comment: Could you give an example what to do?